# Unable to connect to mongo db that i started via docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I am starting a mongo db via docker compose and I am unable to connect to the database now inside the container.
this is my docker compose

```
  mongodb:
    image: <from my private registry>
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass123
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
```

I used docker compose up command to start the container.
now i am trying to enter the mongo container and connect to db, i see the following  error

```
> docker exec -it mymongo /bin/sh
 mongo -u admin -p
 MongoDB shell version v4.2.23
 Enter password: 
 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
 2022-11-23T05:21:04.225+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
 connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:353:17
 @(connect):2:6
2022-11-23T05:21:04.228+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
 2022-11-23T05:21:04.228+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Any documentation that i go through, it says the same thing to pass the user creds as i passed in docker compose but its not working.
futher error in logs

```
Creating databases...
Creating service_configs
Error creating database service_configs!
MongoError: command listCollections requires authentication
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/opt/pronghorn/itential-bundle-1-20202_2020.2.2/node_modules/@itential/database/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with docker, but rather with the way authentication works in Mongo DB.

**TL;TR:**

add  `--authenticationDatabase admin` to the login command, i.e.:

`mongo -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase admin`

**Why?**

You are connecting to the default database (which is most likely `test`) as the `admin` user. The `admin` user itself is not defined in the `test` database, but in the `admin` one, so you need to point where the user should be looked for. If you create a new user in the `test` DB and use his credentials to connect, the `--authenticationDatabase admin` won't be necessary anymore.